# Heroku Website - Where is the REDIS HOST credential?

Tags: heroku, redis

I am trying to set the REDIS_HOST in Settings -> Config Vars on the Heroku website.

I have added a "Heroku Redis::Redis" add-on. When I go in to it, I am **expecting** to see a screen like this;

[image]

But instead all I get is this;

[image]

There is nothing on this page relating to a HOST name of any description. There are barely any links and certainly not to a settings page.

Am I missing something obvious? I am a total Heroku newbie and Google is giving me nothing!

Or have Heroku just changed their UI for a laugh?

Comment: Can't see the screens you posted, but in general, if you added an add-on, Heroku will automatically configure any environment variables necessary for interacting with the add on. You probably don't have to configure any environment variables manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this. I'm submitting this answer because I really do not think it's obvious for a beginner.

When a REDIS add-on has finished building, Heroku will automatically generate a `REDIS_URL` key/value pair for you (might take a few minutes). It will look something like this;

```
REDIS_URL = redis://h:p8jnn2hm2a01fm65ssfdkj2@ec2-41-117-183-81.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:11509
```

With this, you can manually create the following config variables using parts of the REDIS_URL value above. For example;

```
REDIS_PASSWORD = p8jnn2hm2a01fm65ssfdkj2
REDIS_HOST = ec2-41-117-183-81.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
REDIS_PORT = 11509
```

For me, that was all I needed to get my site working. I don't understand why they decided to do it this way.

Comment: Only command line can give you this REDIS_URL : heroku redis:credentials